# Auto-filling web forms

Tags: google-chrome, web, google-chrome-extension, inject

I have to create video-tutorial as help. We have a document with help, but customer want video.
I have found chrome extensions for this purpose - Screencastify (https://www.screencastify.com) for recording chrome tab contenct. It is cool that this tool highlight user clicks.

The best trouble is filling forms. I can't find any tool, or chrome extension or something, whitch is able to fill fluently forms. When I am  filling forms, i make some typing errors and typing is not fluent - video tutorial looks unprofesionall and chaotic.

I have tried UI Vision RPA (https://ui.vision/), but this tool does not simulate user click (yes with some extension, but before simulation user click screen becomes green for a while),  but there are no highlighted clicked position.

Is there a tool that can simulate a smooth form fill according to a prepared script or a macro - basically something like an auto-run UI test, such as a keyboard shortcut that is able to simulate mouse clicks and fluently write defined form content?

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of ways to do it. All below three allow record and play back. 
1. VBA macros in excel, 
2. Automated test tools and frameworks like Selenium
3. RPA tools like WinAutomation or automation anywhere etc.

Once you record, you can go to recorded script, correct any spelling mistakes, add any pauses needed, start your screen recorder and play back the script.